# Local variable is not used inside TimerTask

Tags: java, timertask

I am running my code once every start of an hour, but the following line is not executed

```
int lastcyclehour=hour;
```

I cannot resolve why is this. The error I get is "The value of the local variable lastcyclehour is 
     not used" Code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ControlStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //TIMER, runs the code immediately once in the beginning of each hour
        int lastcyclehour=0;
        Timer timer = new Timer();  
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //read Calendar
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//get the hour
                if(!(hour==lastcyclehour)) {

                    //code
                    System.out.println(hour);
                    System.out.println(lastcyclehour);

                    //code
                }

                int lastcyclehour=hour;     
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(tt, 1000, 1000*2);// 
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside your run method try changing int lastcyclehour=hour;  to lastcyclehour=hour; Which is to say remove the "int".

Comment: How do you know that  int lastcyclehour=hour;  is not executing? you are not printing it, or using it.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring two variables of the same name. With the line

```
int lastcyclehour=0;
```

you declare a local variable of the `main` method which never changes. Note that it is even forbidden to change it when you want to access it from an inner class.

With the statement

```
if(!(hour==lastcyclehour)) {
```

you compare that constant with `hour`.

With the line

```
int lastcyclehour=hour;
```

You declare another variable with the name `lastcyclehour` within the `run` method of your inner class which you never use, so it has no effect. To assign a value to an existing variable you *must not* declare it, i.e. not specify a type, just write `lastcyclehour=hour;`. But as said, you can not modify a local variable of a surrounding method from an inner class. To create a mutable variable which remembers its value between different invocations of the `run()` method, you have to declare it as in instance variable of the inner class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //TIMER, runs the code immediately once in the beginning of each hour
    Timer timer = new Timer();  
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        int lastcyclehour = 0;
        public void run() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //read Calendar
            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//get the hour
            if(hour!=lastcyclehour) {

                //code
                System.out.println(hour);
                System.out.println(lastcyclehour);

                //code
                lastcyclehour=hour;     
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(tt, 1000, 1000*2);// 
}
```

Note further, that the assignment `lastcyclehour=hour` has to be inside the conditional code of the `if` statement to ensure that you compare the current hour with the last hour that you performed an action.

Also, the condition `! (a == b)` can be simplified to `a != b`.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Being familiar mainly with Matlab and VBA, the concept of immutable variables is rather strange to me. This answer you provided still gives me "Local variable lastcyclehour defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" whereas final int is not  what I would like to have.

Comment: You can’t get that error with the code I have provided in my answer. If you get that error, your code is different.